# Borsuk - Ulam theorem proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The Borsuk - Ulam says the following : 
For any continuous map $g : S^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ there exist a point $x \in S^{n}$ such that $g(x) = g(-x)$ 
I doubt that It can't be proved by using the knowledge about homology groups likes Brouwer fixed point . 
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The double negative makes your question is hard to parse. Could you edit your question for clarity, please?

Comment: You know the Brouwer fixed point can be proved by the degree of continuous map on $S^{n}$ so I try to find a solution for BUT just use homology group ( I'm learning homology groups ) . But I know that this theorem relates to cohomology or something higher .